# NotFoundHttpException in Laravel 4.2 application

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am getting a laravel error and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code that would be causing the issue.

The issue is:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Routing/­RouteCollection.php148
```

If anyone needs more information please let me know and I will supply.

Edit: Here is the stack trace

```
#0 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1049): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1017): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(746): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(642): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /home/action/workspace/ssbb/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Show us the code. It's a standard 404-error and without seeing what you did exactly, no one can help you

Comment: What page are you trying to see? And how is that page defined (if at all) in your routes.php file?

Comment: HEre is the index page code: `@include('site::_partials/header')

<article>
 <h2>{{ $entry->title }}</h2>
 {{ $entry->body }}
</article>

@include('site::_partials/footer')`

Comment: and here is the route code for that page:
`Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function()
{
 return View::make('site::index')->with('entry', Page::where('slug', 'welcome')->first());
}));`

Comment: Place the above in your question not the comments, it will be a lot more readable in the question. Also, inlcude some more info like the url you are trying to access, and the location of the view file you are trying to call.

Comment: If your view file is `views/site/index.blade.php`, your Route should return `View::make('site.index')`. Use `.` not `::` to separate directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can't post in the comment section I am posting here

My friend you need to tell us which url you are trying to access,

1. As far as your route suggest it should be this in the browser `localhost/laravel/-Your project name-/public/`
2. As @jeemusu pointed out that this portion of your code is wrong

`return View::make('site::index'), it should be ('site.index'),`

3. There is a query constraint which accepts three parameters, you got only two there,
4. In this line 
   `with('entry', Page::where('slug', 'welcome')->first()`
   please tell us what you are really trying to do

Answer (score 0):

this was due to a URL not found so I just added the following code to my */app/start/global.php* which then told me what URL it had trouble finding.

```
App::missing(function($e) 
{ 
    $url = Request::fullUrl(); 
    Log::warning("404 for URL: $url"); 
    return Response::make('404 not found', 404); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check everything using following code. Also filter 404 (NotFoundHttpException) error form your log file. 
File : app/start/global.php

```
 App::error(function(Exception $exception, $errorCode)
{
    $requestUrl = Request::fullUrl(); 
    $userAgent = Request::header('user-agent');

    if($errorCode != 404){
        Log::error('Exception', array(
            'errorCode' => $errorCode,
            'requestUrl' => $requestUrl,
            'userAgent' => $userAgent,
            'context' => $exception,
        ));     
    }

    return Response::view('error-page-path.error-404', array(), 404);
    // Here "error-404" is a blade view file in "error-page-path" directory
});
```